# How to use SQL Server's undocumented -P switch?

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, switch-statement

I am looking for syntax. Actually I need to check of query uses multiple processor by doing parallelism but have single processor machine. I read couple of places -P switch but could not find how to use it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a full walk through of how to use it in [this article](http://blogs.solidq.com/fabianosqlserver/post.aspx?id=43&title=fooling%20statistics%20and%20number%20of%20cpus%20v1).

Simply add `;-P16` to the end of the list of Startup Parameters in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and restart the service.

Upon restart `SELECT cpu_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info` should indicate that SQL Server thinks you have 16 processors.

You might also consider

```
DBCC OPTIMIZER_WHATIF(CPUs, 16) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

As a less intrusive (but equally undocumented) way of achieving the same end. [More details on that one here.](http://sqlity.net/en/828/optimizer-what-if-i-had-more-cpus/)